# Properly compressing KML file in Linux OS

Tags: google-maps, kml, kmz

I am trying to compress a KML file using gzip on a Linux system

```
gzip -cvf somefile.kml > somefile.kmz
```

When I go to try and verify the new KMZ file in Google Earth, I receive the following error:

> Open of file "somefile.kmz" failed: Parse error at line 1, column 0: not well-formed (invalid token)

What happened?

Comment: `gzip` and `zip` outputs are not equivalent formats. KMZ requires `zip`

Answer (score 1):

Shout-out to @Vince for the help:

**Terminal Code**

```
zip -9 somefile.zip somefile.kml
mv -f somefile.zip somefile.kmz
```

*-9 is for best zip compression*

This process can also be optimized by running:

```
zip -9 somefile.kmz somefile.kml
```